# how to retrive data from a table using mysql which has a parent child relation ship?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 3 rows like cat_id,cat_name,cat_parent.

My table will look like:

```
-------------------------------------
|cat_id   |   cat_name   | cat_parent
-------------------------------------
| 1       |  Electronics | 0
| 2       |  mobile      | 1
| 3       |  ac          | 1
| 4       |  Furniture   | 0
| 5       |  Chair       | 4
```

I would like to select the parent category and its child using MySql single query.

any help?

Comment: and what have you tried

Comment: use `self join` follow this link `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm` to understand

Comment: what is unique between the child and parent tables

Comment: Known or unknown depth / amount of children ?

Comment: Thanks very much @Rahul and Agha Umair Ahmed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a depth of 2 or 3:

```
SELECT
  l0.cat_name,
  l1.cat_name,
  l3.cat_name
FROM      categories l0
JOIN      categories l1 ON l0.cat_id = l1.cat_parent
LEFT JOIN categories l2 ON l1.cat_id = l2.cat_parent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    A.cat_id as cat_id,
    A.cat_name child_id,
    A.cat_parent as parent_id,
    B.cat_name as parent_name
FROM `cat` A
JOIN `cat` B ON 
    A.cat_parent=B.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
    a.cat_id,
    a.cat_name,
    a.cat_parent,
    b.cat_name as child
from
    table as a,
    table as b
where
    a.cat_parent = b.cat_id
```